# Pandas.io.sql read_frame() and to_csv() methods show the output with an additional column

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, pandas

Here's the sqlite query which i need to execute to store the output into a csv file using pandas.io.sql:

```
sql2 = "select raw_contact_id as ID, group_concat(data1) as DETAILS from data group by raw_contact_id"
table2 = sql.read_frame(sql2, conn2)
table2.to_csv(cont_output, headers=True, index=False, encoding="utf8")
```

But I get the output as this:

```
ID   |  DETAILS |
1346 |  A       | P
1347 |  B       | Q
1349 |  C       | R
1350 |  D       | S
```

The DETAILS column is getting split into two columns in the csv file. When I execute this query in terminal I get the proper output with all the details under the DETAILS column. What is wrong with this query execution?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The default separator between values in a group is comma (“,”). To
>   specify a separator explicitly, use SEPARATOR followed by the string
>   literal value that should be inserted between group values. To
>   eliminate the separator altogether, specify SEPARATOR ''.

This means you get `A,P` for `DETAILS`, which gets split into two columns for the csv because of the `,`.

To fix, you could change the seperator in the query, or probably in `.to_csv()`.

Comment: Tried with different separators but the same problem. The second column gets split. The same query works fine in terminal when i save output using sqlite3 .output stdout. to_csv does not seem to have enough options to avoid this splitting..:(

Comment: @JonSnow - What if you use `SEPARATOR ''` (2 single quotes!) in `group_concat()` as a first test? i.e. using no seperator.

Comment: Nope. It does not work that way. If I use any separator in query , the to_csv method output all strings separately in several columns resulting in the DETAILS column containing a single string only and remaining string in adjacent columns..!

Comment: @JonSnow - Did you try using no seperator at all (as a test)? like: `group_concat(data1 SEPARATOR '') as DETAILS` - this should give `AP`. Or how do your fields look like before `.to_csv()`?

Comment: The group_concat(X,Y) takes the Y argument as separator and yes i tried with space separator. It splits the second column into multiple columns. Tried everything.

Comment: @JonSnow - I was not talking about a space, but no separator at all (2 single quotes with nothing in between), as a test. Or you could surround the field with double quotes maybe.

Comment: Tried the no separator option as well, but the thing is when you specify exclusively the separator option, it divides the column indefinitely.

Comment: @JonSnow - Could you provide some sample data of the contents from table2 before conversion to csv, and a sample of the raw generated csv data?

Comment: I did try out the separator option in to_csv method and it did work! sep=' ' option is available in the to_csv() method.